# How to parse protobuf data of Envelope.Payload.Data?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, hyperledger-fabric

I’m using Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK to get a transaction by txId. The return object includes Transaction Information.

```
TransactionInfo txInfo = channel.queryTransactionByID(txId);
Common.Envelope envelope = txInfo.getEnvelope();
Common.Payload payload = Common.Payload.parseFrom(envelope.getPayload());
```

The `Payload` message includes headers and data. I can parse headers by using `Common.Header.ChannelHeader` and `Common.Header.SignatureHeader`.

```
Common.ChannelHeader channelHeader = Common.ChannelHeader.parseFrom(payload.getHeader().getChannelHeader());
Common.SignatureHeader signatureHeader = Common.SignatureHeader.parseFrom(payload.getHeader().getSignatureHeader());
```

The problem is, I cannot see any message type to get data from `Payload`.

My expectation would be like,

```
SomeMessage someMsg = SomeMessage.parseFrom(payload.getData());
```

What is the ideal approach to get a data object?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Driden Myung's tip, Finally found a way to parse QSCC responses into TxReadWriteSet or even KVRWSet !! 
Here is an example:

```
TransactionInfo txInfo = channel.queryTransactionByID(txId);
Common.Envelope envelope = txInfo.getEnvelope();
Common.Payload payload = Common.Payload.parseFrom(envelope.getPayload());
FabricTransaction.Transaction transaction = FabricTransaction.Transaction.parseFrom(payload.getData());
FabricTransaction.TransactionAction action = transaction.getActionsList().get(0); // 0 is a index
FabricTransaction.ChaincodeActionPayload chaincodeActionPayload = FabricTransaction.ChaincodeActionPayload.parseFrom(action.getPayload());
FabricProposalResponse.ProposalResponsePayload prp = FabricProposalResponse.ProposalResponsePayload.parseFrom(chaincodeActionPayload.getAction().getProposalResponsePayload());
FabricProposal.ChaincodeAction ca = FabricProposal.ChaincodeAction.parseFrom(prp.getExtension());
Rwset.TxReadWriteSet txrws = Rwset.TxReadWriteSet.parseFrom(ca.getResults());
TxReadWriteSetInfo txrwsInfo = new TxReadWriteSetInfo(txrws);
KvRwset.KVRWSet kvrwSet = txrwsInfo.getNsRwsetInfo(0).getRwset();
KvRwset.KVWrite kvWrite = kvrwSet.getWrites(0);
String writeVal = kvWrite.getValue().toStringUtf8();
```

Comment: Fabric version larger than 1.4.x (^2.0.0) need to use "TransactionPackage" in place of FabricTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```java
FabricTransaction.Transaction transaction =  FabricTransaction.Transaction.parseFrom(payload.getData());
```

After that,

```java
FabricTransaction.TransactionAction action = transaction.getActionsList().get(index);
FabricTransaction.ChaincodeActionPayload chaincodeActionPayload = FabricTransaction.ChaincodeActionPayload.parseFrom(action.getPayload());
chaincodeActionPayload.getAction().getEndorsementsList().forEach(endorsement -> {
    // This is my current point
    ???? endorser = ????.parseFrom(endorsement.getEndorser());
});
```

Let me add if I can find more. Anybody add comments welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced a similar problem to get the **request data from a transaction.**

The following code will help to get the transaction request data of a transaction

**Fabric SDK version : 2.1.4**

```
        // get transaction from transaction ID
        TransactionInfo txInfo = channel.queryTransactionByID(txId);
        // transaction is stored inside the envelope containing the payload and signature
        Common.Envelope envelope = txInfo.getEnvelope();
        // parse payload from the envelope
        Common.Payload payload = Common.Payload.parseFrom(envelope.getPayload());
        // payload contains Header and Data. We are parsing data to get the transaction
        TransactionPackage.Transaction transaction = TransactionPackage.Transaction.parseFrom(payload.getData());
        // get first action from the transaction action list. it contains input and other details
        TransactionPackage.TransactionAction action = transaction.getActionsList().get(0); // 0 is a index
        // chaincode action payload contains input parameters. So we are taking the action payload
        TransactionPackage.ChaincodeActionPayload chaincodeActionPayload = TransactionPackage.ChaincodeActionPayload.parseFrom(action.getPayload());
        // chaincode ProposalPayload contains Input and TransientMap. We are parsing actionPayload to proposalPayload
        ProposalPackage.ChaincodeProposalPayload prp = ProposalPackage.ChaincodeProposalPayload.parseFrom(chaincodeActionPayload.getChaincodeProposalPayload());
        // parse the input to chaincodeInvocationSpec so that we can unmarshal the input
        Chaincode.ChaincodeInvocationSpec chaincodeInvocationSpec = Chaincode.ChaincodeInvocationSpec.parseFrom(prp.getInput());

        // get the input and parse the arg list and get input arguments 
       chaincodeInvocationSpec.getChaincodeSpec().getInput().getArgsList().get(ChaincodeInput.ARGS_FIELD_NUMBER).toStringUtf8();
```